# Imhistmatch function is not working properly

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram

I'm using the `imhistmatch` function, but the result is a 2D matrix that is all ones. I was expecting another result.

[image: ALGORITHM]

```
a=imread('dalgic.png');
a=rgb2gray(a);
[r,c]=size(a);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    esitlenmis=histeq(a);
    ort_esitlenmis=fft2(esitlenmis);%orthogonal transform is fft.
    log_ort_esitlenmis=log(1+abs(ort_esitlenmis));

    ort=fft2(a);
    ort=fft2(ort);%2nd fft
    log_ort=log(1+abs(ort));

    matched=imhistmatch(log_ort,log_ort_esitlenmis);
```

Comment: Two FFTs in a row return something quite similar to the input. What is the point of that? Are you sure the “orthogonal transform” is an FFT?

Comment: Actually I don't know the point of using two FFTs .I'm trying to implement this paper https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8652298 .I'm sure that the orthogonal transform is FFT.Thanks for attention.

Comment: I don't know about the FFT, but I think you should add: `a = im2double(a);` after `a=rgb2gray(a);` (set range to [0,1]), and `log_ort = log_ort / max(log_ort(:));` and `log_ort_esitlenmis = log_ort_esitlenmis / max(log_ort_esitlenmis(:));` before `matched=imhistmatch(log_ort,log_ort_esitlenmis);` (set range to [0, 1]).